# Better (more performant) way to get specific DIVs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I want to add a specific DIV to other DIVs of a defined class. Because the page changes regularly I do this on every DOM-Change. This happens quite often and there are a lot of DIVs (up to a few 1000) that meet the criteria.

(This is an extension so I cannot modifiy the source)

I do it this way:

```
$('.Qg').each(function() {
  if ($(this).parent().find('.quickShare').length === 0)
  {      
    $(this).before('<div class="quickShare">(some more html)<br/></div>');
  }
});
```

That works but does not seem to be very performant, mainly because of the "each" - Loop

Is there a more elegant (and especially performant) way to get only those DIVs which's parent do not contain my DIV (something like `$('.Qg').parent().without('quickShare').each(function(){});` (pseudocode)?

Update: To make it clearer a DOM-Example:

```
<div class="anOuterDiv>
  <div class="Qg">something here</div>
</div>

<div class="anotherOuterDiv">
  <div class="quickShare">already added</div>
  <div class="Qg">something here</div>
</div>
```

I want to Add the "quickShare" div before the "Qg", but only if it does not exist. (So I want to get the upper Qg, but not the lower Qg)

Comment: so, you don't want to select divs with class `quickShare` ?

Comment: `$(this).parent().find('.quickShare')` can be `$(this).siblings('.quickShare')` I think.

Comment: Is your pseudocode will be helpful, if i answer it as true code ?

Comment: can you be sure that `quickShare` will always be before `.Qg` ?

Comment: Yes. Because I am the only one adding it (in this code) :) Thanks for your help. Barmars code worked.

Comment: @OleAlbers Hey, check out my new answer with a demo. Its too small and performant when compared to Barmer's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give all the parents of `.Qg` the class `QgContainer`, then do:

```
$(".QgContainer:not(:has(.quickShare)) > .Qg").each(function() {
    ...
});
```

Since you can't change the site, try:

```
$(".Qg").filter(function() {
    return $(this).siblings(".quickShare").length == 0);
}).each(function() {
    ...
});
```

Comment: I added a solution using `.filter()`.

Comment: Looks promising. I will try that. Please keep both codes in your answer, might help others. Perhaps I can even find a parent class up the dom that fits the first solution

Comment: Found one :) Seems to be much smoother than before

Answer (score 1):

You can filter each `.Qg` that's not preceded by a `.quickShare` sibling and then apply `.before()` on that:

```
$('.Qg')
  .filter(function() {
    var node = this.previousSibling; // start with previous sibling

    while (node) {
      if (node.className == 'quickShare') {
        return false; // we found one
      }
      node = node.previousSibling; // keep trying with previous sibling
    }

    return true;
  })
  .before('<div class="quickShare">(some more html)<br/></div>');
```

Answer (score 1):

As you wanted `better(more perfomant)` then you could consider using pure Javascript.

HTML

```
<div class="anOuterDiv1">
    <div class="Qg">something here</div>
</div>
<div class="anOuterDiv2">
    <div class="quickShare">already added</div>
    <div class="Qg">something here</div>
</div>
<div class="anOuterDiv3">
    <div class="Qg">something here</div>
</div>
<div class="anOuterDiv4">
    <div class="quickShare">already added</div>
    <div class="Qg">something here</div>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.getElementsByClassName('Qg'), function (Qg) {
    var parentNode = Qg.parentNode,
        quickShares = parentNode.getElementsByClassName('quickShare'),
        newQuickShare;

    if(!quickShares.length) {
        newQuickShare = document.createElement('div');
        newQuickShare.className = 'quickShare';
        newQuickShare.textContent = 'Newly added';
        parentNode.insertBefore(newQuickShare, Qg);
    }
});
```

On [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/bYRR5/)

Next we should actually compare it against some jQuery, so we will use the accepted answer.

```
$(".Qg").filter(function() {
    return $(this).siblings(".quickShare").length == 0;
}).each(function() {
    $(this).before('<div class="quickShare">Newly added</div>');
});
```

On [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/skcvG/)

And now lets see how they perform on [jsPerf](http://jsperf.com/22126675)

Answer (score 0):

This time it will definitely work:

```
 $('div:only-child.Qg').each(function(){
   $(this).before('<div class="quickShare">(some more html)<br/></div>');
 });
```

Try this. This is very easy and readable and small and performant.

jsFiddle Demo http://jsfiddle.net/VS6mG/

Comment: Sorry pal. I really appreciate your help, but this does not work. I reduced my example to make it more readable. In the real environment there are dozens of siblings to "Qg" (and not always the same amount)

Comment: @OleAlbers does it contain elements other than `.quickShare` ?